# YIN algorithm to python for finding fundamental frequency

Tags: python, algorithm, audio, signal-processing

I am trying to find fundamental frequency with YIN algorithm in python.

I am at step 2 of [this document](http://audition.ens.fr/adc/pdf/2002_JASA_YIN.pdf).

I need to find index of 0 value from this code:

```
def auto(t, lag, samples):
    total_index = len(samples)
    zero_padded = np.append(samples, np.zeros(total_index))

    r = 0
    for j in range(t+1, t+total_index):
        r += zero_padded[j] * zero_padded[j+lag]

    return r

diff = []
rt0 = auto(0, 0, samples)
for lag in range(0, 2700):
    diff.append(rt0 + auto(lag, 0, samples) - (2*auto(0, lag, samples)))
```

as mentioned in document:

[image]

[image]

but I cannot find any 0 value index except index(lag) = 0.

[image]

1. what codes should be fixed?

and the document said they did cumulative mean to nomalize.

2. what is cumulative mean nomalization?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, one ignores the AMDF result with a lag at or near zero, and looks for a non-zero AMDF lag with a small but usually non-zero difference.  Which non-zero AMDF to select is known as the octave problem, and may involve weighting the difference function.

Comment: Isn't the step 2 Difference Function? The document converted difference function with ACF, but it said 
"Conversely, an unknown period may be found by forming the difference function: and searching for the values of t for which the function is zero"

So, I tried to find a lag at zero which does not appear on my graph

Comment: Noise of many kinds will prevent finding a zero, look for something small instead.